# How to switch JS contexts(to iframe context of different domain) programatically using Puppeteer or Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I want to use Puppeteer to get data from selectors that are placed inside an iframe on a page which runs on a different domain from it's parent's frame domain.
I am not the owner of any of the domains therefore - can't use frame.postMessage.

tried to refer to the selector with

```
document.querySelector('#selector_inside_iframe')
```

but since the selector inside an iframe - it is invisible from the main context. When tried to use

```
document.querySelector('#selector_inside_iframe').contentWindow.document
```

because the iframe uses different domain - it is blocked by CORS.
It works when changing manually the JS context in the JS contexts dropdown on the console tab of Chrome, however, it need to be done using Puppeteer.

[image: JS context dropdown]

I expect to get reference to node '#selector_inside_iframe' but getting the following error if not changing context inside Chrome dev-tools:

```
'Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://blah.some_domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame'
```

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve it by using Puppeter's `ElementHandle.contentFrame()` .

first get reference to the `iframe` selector as `ElementHandle` object using

> `const iframeHandle = await page.$('iframe')`

then refer to the `iframe` context with `ElementHandle.contentFrame()` like this:

> `const contentFrame = await iframeHandle.contentFrame()`

Now to query the html/css selectors inside the iframe just use the `contentFrame`
such as the following:

> `contentFrame.$('.data_class')`